# Is it possible autodownload Grails plugin sources?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

Is it possible to automatically download sources of grails plugins and its dependencies like it does by maven?

It is crazy to attach sources by hand

Comment: Hm, my Intellij IDEA 11.1 Ultimate shows me sources w/o any special configuration. What version do you use?

Comment: The question is still open. IDEA attaches module with plugin sources. But sometimes I doesn't have this module. How can I recreate / regenerate it again?

Comment: Well. May be I'm wrong. I have found plugins section. Strange but `CTRL-SHIFT-N` dialog doesn't use plugins sources

Comment: Looks like IDEA has problems with muli module Grails project